# Viewport3D with orthographic camera clipping

Tags: c#, wpf, clipping, orthographic, viewport3d

When using the ViewPort3D with an orthographic camera, the 3D model is clipping as you can see on the 2nd link below. It's like the view is based on the perspective camera and doesn't show what is behind it, even though it uses an orthographic camera.

[View of the entire 3D model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9sVo.png)

[Perspective view & Orthographic view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lh1mf.png)

Used code to generate picture above

```
Used code to generate pictures above (toggling Orthographic to True/False)

<Window x:Class="HelixToolkitTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:helix="http://helix-toolkit.org/wpf"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <GeometryModel3D x:Key="GeometryModel">

                <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                    <MeshGeometry3D
                 TriangleIndices="0,1,2 3,4,5 "
                 Normals="0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 "
                 TextureCoordinates="0,0 1,0 1,1 1,1 0,1 0,0 "
                 Positions="-0.5,-0.5,0.5 0.5,-0.5,0.5 0.5,0.5,0.5 0.5,0.5,0.5 -0.5,0.5,0.5 -0.5,-0.5,0.5 " />
                </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>

                <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                    <MaterialGroup>
                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.25" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.75" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="LimeGreen" Offset="1" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                    </MaterialGroup>
                </GeometryModel3D.Material>

                <GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                    <ScaleTransform3D ScaleX="50" ScaleY="1" ScaleZ="1"/>
                </GeometryModel3D.Transform>
            </GeometryModel3D>
    <DirectionalLight x:Key="DirectionalLight" Color="#FFFFFF" Direction="-0.612372,-0.5,-0.612372" />
</Window.Resources>
<UniformGrid Columns="3">
    <GroupBox Header="Perspective camera">
        <Viewport3D>
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera FarPlaneDistance="Infinity" NearPlaneDistance="0.1" LookDirection="12.064,-1.167,-0.831" UpDirection="-0.73,0.071,0.679"
                            Position="-12.064,1.167,0.831"/>
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
            <ModelVisual3D Content="{StaticResource DirectionalLight}"/>
            <ModelVisual3D Content="{StaticResource GeometryModel}"/>
        </Viewport3D>
    </GroupBox>
    <GroupBox Header="Orthographic camera">
        <Viewport3D>
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <OrthographicCamera FarPlaneDistance="Infinity" NearPlaneDistance="0.1" LookDirection="12.064,-1.167,-0.831" UpDirection="-0.73,0.071,0.679"
                            Position="-12.064,1.167,0.831" Width="9.313"/>
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
            <ModelVisual3D Content="{StaticResource DirectionalLight}"/>
            <ModelVisual3D Content="{StaticResource GeometryModel}"/>
        </Viewport3D>
    </GroupBox>
```

Any idea on how to resolve this problem?

Thanks,

Edit : I actually found the solution, you just need to set the NearPlaneDistance of the orthographic camera to -Infinity, see code below:

```
<Window x:Class="HelixToolkitTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:helix="http://helix-toolkit.org/wpf"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <GeometryModel3D x:Key="GeometryModel">

                <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                    <MeshGeometry3D
                 TriangleIndices="0,1,2 3,4,5 "
                 Normals="0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 "
                 TextureCoordinates="0,0 1,0 1,1 1,1 0,1 0,0 "
                 Positions="-0.5,-0.5,0.5 0.5,-0.5,0.5 0.5,0.5,0.5 0.5,0.5,0.5 -0.5,0.5,0.5 -0.5,-0.5,0.5 " />
                </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>

                <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                    <MaterialGroup>
                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.25" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.75" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="LimeGreen" Offset="1" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                    </MaterialGroup>
                </GeometryModel3D.Material>

                <GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                    <ScaleTransform3D ScaleX="50" ScaleY="1" ScaleZ="1"/>
                </GeometryModel3D.Transform>
            </GeometryModel3D>
    <DirectionalLight x:Key="DirectionalLight" Color="#FFFFFF" Direction="-0.612372,-0.5,-0.612372" />
</Window.Resources>
<UniformGrid Columns="3">
    <GroupBox Header="Perspective camera">
        <Viewport3D>
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera FarPlaneDistance="Infinity" NearPlaneDistance="0.1" LookDirection="12.064,-1.167,-0.831" UpDirection="-0.73,0.071,0.679"
                            Position="-12.064,1.167,0.831"/>
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
            <ModelVisual3D Content="{StaticResource DirectionalLight}"/>
            <ModelVisual3D Content="{StaticResource GeometryModel}"/>
        </Viewport3D>
    </GroupBox>
    <GroupBox Header="Orthographic camera">
        <Viewport3D>
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <OrthographicCamera FarPlaneDistance="Infinity" NearPlaneDistance="-Infinity" LookDirection="12.064,-1.167,-0.831" UpDirection="-0.73,0.071,0.679"
                            Position="-12.064,1.167,0.831" Width="9.313"/>
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
            <ModelVisual3D Content="{StaticResource DirectionalLight}"/>
            <ModelVisual3D Content="{StaticResource GeometryModel}"/>
        </Viewport3D>
    </GroupBox>
```

Comment: What do you expect? I can't see what's wrong with the code and the behaviour. You use one GeometryModel3D, and you see it, form both camera types.

Comment: I was expecting to see the whole model (with the yellow part), like in the picture below : [Perspective view & Orthographic view](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fslLG.png).
But it's alright now, I found the solution (see edited question above).

Comment: Then move your camera farther away.

Comment: Rather than setting a negative NearPlaneDistance, which Microsoft recommends against, move the camera farther away, as AgentFire suggested. Also, try increasing the magnitude of your LookDirection vector. Normally that doesn't matter, except that the Helix ZoomToExtents method re-positions the camera using the LookDirection vector as a relative offset.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you. Testing several solutions finally I was able to find the solution.

You have to **increase** or define the **FarPlaneDistance** property of **PerspectiveCamera**.

Good luck